# Whats wrong in this ASP.Net web.config connection string?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, web-config

i have attached database file C324040_volvo.mdf to my mssql2005 management studio whose name in mssql2005 management studio is ASPNETDB

but page doesn't found the database....and the site doesn't load

i m testing my site in my local computer ...

```
<connectionStrings>
       <add name="connectionString" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\C324040_volvo.mdf;Database=ASPNETDB;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=False"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Page searches for a log time ...

Answer (score 0):

If you've already added it to SQL Server then you shouldn't need

```
AttachDbFilename=C:\C324040_volvo.mdf
```

If it isn't already attached, then SQL probably doesn't have rights to the root of C: and you should move it.

Comment: then what will be my modified connection string ?